# Linking the default size of a ggvis chart rendered in shiny to the dimensions of a wellPanel

Tags: r, svg, shiny, ggvis, vega

I've got a pretty cool shiny app going to look at the results of some modeling I'm doing at work. One of the devices I use is a ggvis line chart that sits in a wellPanel. I'd like to deploy the app for viewing online, but I know from looking at the app on normal sized screens (laptops) that the ggvis plot spills over the borders of the wellPanel. For me not a huge deal since I have a huge screen and if I was looking at it on a small screen I know I can just resize the ggvis charts interactively, but I don't want to tell folks to do that. If I re-size the ggvis charts the wellPanel responds so there must be some link between the size of these two objects.

So is there a way to set the default size of a rendered ggvis chart to the default size of the container it's in regardless of the users screen size? I know ggvis is rendered with SVG and so exploring that might be fruitful. I haven't worked directly with SVG or Vega. Example code is below and here is a  [link](https://miles2knowportal.shinyapps.io/ExampleResults/)  to the app hosted on shinyapps. Any thoughts?

**note:** I posted the code obviously for folks to work with. I guess I just want to be clear that I'm not asking a question about how to get this shiny app to work - It's more how to style it. Of course I welcome other suggestions though. Cheers.

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(navbarPage("Results Viewer", #theme="bootstrap.css",

  tabPanel("Summary Results",
   fluidRow(
      column(2,
       wellPanel(
        uiOutput("regionO"),
        br(),
        uiOutput("scenarioO"),
        br(),
        uiOutput("fuelO"),
        uiOutput("tmpO")
        )
      ),
     column(5,
       wellPanel(style="position: relative;", 
        h5("Employment",align="center"),
        ggvisOutput("plot1")
        )
      ),
     column(5,
      wellPanel(style="position: relative;", 
        h5("Gross Regional Product (Million Dollars)",align="center"),
        ggvisOutput("plot2")
        )
      )
     ) 
    )
   )
  )
```

**server.r**

```
librarylibrary(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

observe({

###### Define Controls ####### 

output$regionO <- renderUI({ checkboxGroupInput(inputId="regionI", label = h4("Regions"), 
        choices = list("Western", "Central", "Southern","Northern", "Capital", "Hudson"),
                   selected="Capital")
}) 

output$scenarioO <- renderUI({ selectInput(inputId="scenarioI", label = h4("Scenario"), 
        choices = list("Low Units, Low Tech"="Lo,Lo" ,"Low Units, High Tech"="Lo,Hi","High Units, Low Tech"="Hi,Lo","High Units, High Tech"="Hi,Hi"),
                   selected="Lo,Lo")
})

output$fuelO <- renderUI({ selectInput(inputId="fuelI", label = h4("Fuel Price"), 
        choices = list("High Price" = "Hi", "Low Price" = "Lo"),
                   selected="Lo")
})

output$tmpO <- renderUI({actionButton("resetI", label = "Reset")}) 

###### Define Data ########### 

if(!is.null(input$resetI)){

chooseRJ <- reactive({ 

     chooseD <- expJ %>% filter(Scenario == input$scenarioI, Region %in% input$regionI, Price == input$fuelI)
     return(chooseD)
 })

sPlot1 <- reactive({

     chooseRJ %>% ggvis(~factor(Period),~Total,stroke=~Region) %>% layer_lines(strokeWidth:=2.5) %>% 
     add_axis("x",title="Analysis Period") %>% add_axis("y",title="Jobs") %>% scale_numeric("y",zero=TRUE) 
}) 

sPlot1 %>% bind_shiny("plot1") 


chooseRV <- reactive({ 

     chooseD <- expV %>% filter(Scenario == input$scenarioI, Region %in% input$regionI, Price == input$fuelI)
     return(chooseD)
})

sPlot2 <- reactive({

        chooseRV %>% ggvis(~factor(Period),~Total,stroke=~Region) %>% layer_lines(strokeWidth:=2.5) %>% 
        add_axis("x",title="Analysis Period") %>% add_axis("y",title="Gross Regional Product $M") %>% scale_numeric("y",zero=TRUE) 
})  

sPlot2 %>% bind_shiny("plot2")  

 } # Test ui controls exist 

}) # End Observeer

}) # End Shiny Server
```

**Global.r**

```
##### Play data ####################

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

expJ <- data.frame(Region=rep(c("Western","Central","Southern","Northern","Capital","Hudson"),times=4,each=8),
                Scenario=rep(c("Lo,Lo","Lo,Hi","Hi,Lo","Hi,Hi"),each=48),
                Price=rep(c("Hi","Lo"),times=24,each=4),
                Period=rep(c(1,2,3,4),times=48),
                Total=rnorm(192,5,1.5))

expV <- data.frame(Region=rep(c("Western","Central","Southern","Northern","Capital","Hudson"),times=4,each=8),
                Scenario=rep(c("Lo,Lo","Lo,Hi","Hi,Lo","Hi,Hi"),each=48),
                Price=rep(c("Hi","Lo"),times=24,each=4),
                Period=rep(c(1,2,3,4),times=48),
                Total=rgamma(192,10,1.78))
```

Comment: Is the code in server.R correct?

Comment: I get an error in line 10 of the server function

Comment: global.R doesnt seem to relate to the rest of the app

Comment: Where are sPlot1 and sPlot2

Comment: So sorry I forgot a few (<-) = (&lt;-)...ahhh

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html talks about getting the width and height of an outputId, but when I tried to get session$clientData$output_plot1_width, I always get NULL. Not sure if that's b/c the client isn't setting it or if something else is going on